# Method on django model to return the count of a foreign key

Tags: django

I want a method on a django model that returns the count of members in a foreignkey. I'd prefer it to be a class method (and not annotation) because I want to serialize it and send it via javascript without involving templates.

Based on previous answers to similar questions, I believed the following sort of structure would work (some attributes deleted for the sake of simplicity):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    likedby = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='liked')

    def likes(self):
        return self.likedby_set.count()
```

But when I run this I get `AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'likedby_set'`. Anyone know why this doesn't work?

Edit: Thanks for the help with all this. I'm now thinking: would it make more sense to restructure the models by adding a Like class like so?

```
class Like(models.Model):
    liker = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')
```

Then perhaps in the Post class I could `return likes_set.count()` (assuming that's valid)

Edit 2: In case useful to people who may look at this post in the future, the above solution won't work because `likes` isn't a queryset; it's just a related name pointing to the people who liked the post. In order to gather those people up correctly into a queryset and make the count, I did the following in my serialization defined within the model: `likes = self.likes.all().count()`, which seems to work.

Comment: Can you share your views.py?

Comment: `likedby` for a post is just a single user, so there is no `_set` available.

Comment: You'll want to use ManyToManyField; something like `likedby = models.ManyToManyField('User', ...`

Comment: Ah, so that's why the _set trick doesn't work. I'm thinking about restructuring the models and creating a Like model, which may make more sense than having likes a s a field on Post